# Remove all duplicates except latest occurrence in big query standard sql based off two columns

Tags: google-bigquery, duplicates

If I have a table in big query that contains the following

```
fruit   color   quantity   age   other_field
apple   red      3         1      foo
grapes  green    5         1      young
apple   green    1         3      word
apple   red      4         5      bar
```

How would I delete all rows except the last instance containing the same fruit & color column so that my table would then look like this

```
fruit   color   quantity   age   other_field
grapes  green    5         1      young
apple   green    1         3      word
apple   red      4         5      bar
```

Essentially only keeping a single row for every unique pair of fruit and color in big query standard sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'apple' fruit, 'red' color, 3 quantity, 1 age, 'foo' other_field UNION ALL
  SELECT 'grapes', 'green', 5, 1, 'young' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'apple', 'green', 1, 3, 'word' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'apple', 'red', 4, 5, 'bar' 
)
SELECT fruit, color, 
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(quantity, age, other_field) ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY fruit, color
```

with result

```
Row fruit   color   quantity    age other_field  
1   apple   red     4           5   bar  
2   grapes  green   5           1   young    
3   apple   green   1           3   word
```

Another version of same is:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE
  ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY fruit, color
```

with same result ...  but obviously I like this version better :o)

Comment: Ahh interesting! So does a dual group by need something to order by? i.e. what if the extra columns were just all arbitrary strings with no particular significance?

Comment: if you will not use some field as an order - you can just omit this part  - but in this case you will get random winner. usually there is always something that identifies order  - like timestamp for example. in your case - based on wording and example of expected result in your question - i thought `age` is such a field, but this can be `quantity` - it really depends on your business logic. makes sense?

Comment: Perfect sense, thank you for the clear and concise explanation!

Comment: great. please consider also voting up the answer - it is equally important on SO